# back button in title bar in uwp not visible

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, back-button

I am trying to use back button for my uwp app. I have using the below code for this. But it is not visible. Please help me.

```
  public class TitleBarBehavior : DependencyObject, IBehavior
{
    public DependencyObject AssociatedObject { get; private set; }

    public void Attach(DependencyObject associatedObject)
    {
        var newTitleBar = associatedObject as UIElement;
        if (newTitleBar == null)
            throw new ArgumentException(
                "TitleBarBehavior can be attached only to UIElement");

        Window.Current.SetTitleBar(newTitleBar);
    }

    public void Detach() { }

    public bool IsChromeless
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsChromelessProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsChromelessProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsChromelessProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsChromeless",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(TitleBarBehavior),
        new PropertyMetadata(false, OnIsChromelessChanged));

    private static void OnIsChromelessChanged(DependencyObject d,
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar
            .ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = (bool)e.NewValue;
    }
}
```

and the code in app.xaml.cs

```
SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += OnBackRequested;

            //SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible;
            SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility = rootFrame.CanGoBack ?
                      AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible :
                      AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Collapsed;


 private void OnBackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e)
        {
            Frame FromrootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
            strpage = FromrootFrame.Content.ToString();
            //if (rootFrame != null)
            //{
            //    Type whatpageisit = rootFrame.SourcePageType;
            //    // handle this page type
            //}
            if (FromrootFrame.CanGoBack)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                FromrootFrame.GoBack();
            }
        }
```

But the error I am getting is 
" The type 'IBehavior' exists in both 'Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e3'"

can anyone please tell me how can I solve it.

Comment: I have added 2 nuget packages of same assembly Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity, now I have removed one then also the back button is not visible. But there s no error.

Answer (score 1):

When you navigate to a new page or back to the previous page, the root frame will raise the event `OnNavigated`, you need update the visibility of the back button in this event, so try using the following code:

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    ……
    frame.OnNavigated += Frame_Navigated;
    ……
}

private void Frame_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var frame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
    SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility = frame.CanGoBack ?
                  AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible :
                  AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Collapsed;
}
```

As to your reference error, I suggest your remove all installed XAML behavior references, then install this nuget package:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed
```